# How to prevent too large files from being uploaded before upload starts even if client bypasses front end validation

Tags: php

On the back end I validate the file size by reading `$_FILES['input_name']['size']` and returning an error message if the file size is too large. However, the back end code runs after the file has already been uploaded and this wastes the time and bandwidth of the server. I want to validate the file size before the upload begins. Existing solutions suggest that I use JavaScript to validate the file size on the front end. However, front end validation is not guaranteed and can be bypassed by users by modifying page source code. How to validate the file size on the back end and reject the request if the file size is too large without having to wait to receive the entire file first?

---

Edit:

Alright, since it's not possible to get the actual file size on the server side before the upload begins, let's try to think in a different way to increase server efficiency.

I want to make the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` have small values so that the server will not spend hours receiving a very large file. The problem is: The server will display a warning message (not sure if it's visible by default during production) like this:

`Warning: POST Content-Length of 3071934808 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

I want to show my custom error message and hide any warnings/errors displayed in the browser by the server by default during production.

Also I was wondering, let's say if the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are both 40M but the user uploads a 10GB file. Will the server wait for the entire 10GB to be uploaded or will interrupt the request once it reaches 40MB?

Comment: How many people do you realistically think are going to go and modify the front end source to bypass the size check?

Comment: If the upload hits the `upload_max_filesize` limit, I think PHP cancels the request at that point. But this will be a "hard shutdown", it gets you an internal server error, and not chance to react to it from within your script.

Comment: Assuming clients will send a correct `Content-Length` header, you could probably try to handle the request based on that using mod_rewrite or conditionals - but that would only allow you to check on the site of the _whole_ request. If you have only a couple of text fields and a field to upload one single file, that might still ore or less work - but if you allowed multiple uploads in one request, there is no way of telling how big the individual files are, based on the overall request body length.

Comment: @wkl While normal users will not modify the front end source, malicious users or hackers may try to send unexpected requests to attack the server. So I have to think about this case.

Comment: `I want to validate the file size before the upload begins`...the only way to do that is in the browser. So you can do that, but you must accept that someone could bypass it. The second line of defence is in your server. But there is no way to check the size of the file on the server until you receive it, so you must accept that inefficiency. If it turns out you get a lot of malicious usages, another defence is to try blocking them by IP or other means, use captchas or CSRF to defend against bots, and so on. Your defences can be multi-layered

Comment: OK I edited the question. Can you help with the part I added?

Comment: I'm not actually sure about that off the top of my head, someone else might know. Maybe test it on a local  server and see what happens

Comment: I believe that you should research and try the nginX [upload module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) - it is specifically designed for your case. Even better would be if you upload files directly to Amazon S3 from the browser, bypassing your server entirely.